# How to track who have removed permissions of others in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation

In share-point permission settings(both in Document and Library level) is it possible to track who have removed the permissions of others.

Comment: Only with auditing enabled. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Configure-audit-settings-for-a-site-collection-c4ee05e1-2ebd-45f1-a254-d2350aa44ae0

Answer (score 2):

If you enable the audit logging on your site collection level then you can track it.

> You can use the audit feature of Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 to
>   track which users have taken what actions on the sites, content types,
>   lists, libraries, list items, and library files of site collections

If not, enable it now so you will get future actions.this is what on the audit setting page[image]

You check more here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Configure-audit-settings-for-a-site-collection-F5A346D0-EE0F-4412-A5E6-D9B5ABAA1012

Another way, required hard work, you can check the IIS logs and look for the permission page url and see how access it.

Answer (score 2):

I see that you use SharePoint online. 
So It's possible, but you don't set it at library level. Instead it should be set at site collection level. 
Just go to Site Collection Administration - > Site collection audit settings 
and select interesting events for you.
After that you can generate report with Site Collection Administration - > Audit log reports